# How to view complete error message from 'docker stack ps'?

Tags: docker

While following the docker tutorial, I ran into a problem while deploying a stack with the `docker stack deploy` command. The most information on the error I managed to obtain was from running the `docker stack ps` command, which displays a table with an Error column:
[image: docker stack ps output]

This is not a lot of information, even the message is truncated to fit in the table. I have already resolved the original problem but for the future I would like to know: how can I view the complete error message? How would I go about reading the logs?

Comment: Try `docker stack ps --no-trunc` and see if it helps

Comment: @TarunLalwani It does, I can see the full error message now :)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need to use below command for the same

```
docker stack ps --no-trunc
```

You can also find this in the command help by running the `--help` flag:

```
$ docker stack ps --help

Usage:  docker stack ps [OPTIONS] STACK

List the tasks in the stack

Options:
  -f, --filter filter   Filter output based on conditions provided
      --format string   Pretty-print tasks using a Go template
      --no-resolve      Do not map IDs to Names
      --no-trunc        Do not truncate output
  -q, --quiet           Only display task IDs
```